# Show Interstitial In Other Scenes - Admob, SpriteKit, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob, interstitial

How do I show an interstitial ad from admob every x times the user has died or every x times the user does something like presses a button? This is how I showed an interstitial ad on my GameScene and limited ad impressions with a simple if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will only work if you have the GoogleMobileAds.sdk and have imported the googlemobileads module into your GameViewController, and GameScene, OR GameOverScene.

I'll be showing you cross-scene ad implementation and programmatically limiting ad impressions.

First, in your GameViewController:

```
import GoogleMobileAds


class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {



var myAd = GADInterstitial()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.loadAndShow), name: "loadAndShow", object: nil)

}
```

Create two functions at the bottom of your GameViewController:

```
func loadAndShow() {



    myAd = GADInterstitial()
    let request = GADRequest()
    myAd.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    myAd.delegate = self
    myAd.loadRequest(request)



}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

    if (self.myAd.isReady) {

        myAd.presentFromRootViewController(self)



    }



}
```

You are done with GameViewController. Now head to GameOverScene or GameScene, whatever you need.

Create a global int variable:

```
var playCount = Int()
```

In your DidMoveToView say:

```
playCount = 1
```

This part is sort of confusing, kinda, not really. Go to your touchesBegan and find where you add actions to a button if it's pressed. For example, a resetGame button resets the scene. Add this there and increment the playButton Int like so:

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches{



        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if resetGame.containsPoint(location) {
            restartScene()

            playCount += 1


        }
```

Last step. Add these two functions to the bottom of the scene you want to show interstitial ads in:

```
func displayAd() {



 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loadAndShow", object: nil)


}

func checkAd() {


    if playCount % 4 == 0 {

        displayAd()

    }

}

}
```

Now every fourth time that the user presses the reset game button or dies, an interstitial ad should show up. I hope this helps.

*EDIT*: I forgot to tell you to call the checkAd() function. Call this function wherever your players dies. So if you have a Bool variable called died or gameover call it in the same spot. For example..

```
if died == true {
  checkAd()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

import SpriteKit

import GoogleMobileAds

var playCount = Int()

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var banner: GADBannerView!

var myAd = GADInterstitial()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.loadAndShow), name: "loadAndShow", object: nil)

    let scene = MainScene(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))


              // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

    banner.hidden = true

    banner.delegate = self

    banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8889875503423788/7902691359"
    banner.rootViewController = self
    banner.loadRequest(GADRequest())

}

func loadAndShow() {



    myAd = GADInterstitial()
    let request = GADRequest()
    myAd.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-8889875503423788/7902691359")
    myAd.delegate = self
    myAd.loadRequest(request)



}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

    if (self.myAd.isReady) {

        myAd.presentFromRootViewController(self)



    }



}

func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
    banner.hidden = false
}

func adView(bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    banner.hidden = true
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Go up to your class GameViewController where it says UIViewController and add GADInterstitialDelegate

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain how this answers the question? Code dumps are discouraged on StackOverflow: they aren't very helpful as they don't teach people how to solve issues; they just encourage copy-paste coding. Thanks!